# Swift Generics issue

Tags: swift

Right now I want to be able to see if an object is included inside an `Array` so:

```
func isIncluded<U:Comparable>(isIncluded : U) -> Bool
{
    for item in self
    {
        if (item == isIncluded)
        {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

If you notice this function belongs to an `Array` extension. The problem is if add it to this:

```
extension Array{

}
```

I receive the following error:

> Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments

[image]

I understand that I could probably need to tell what kind of objects should be inside the `Array` like so: `T[] <T.GeneratorType.Element: Comparable>`. But it doesn't work as well:

> Braced block of statements is an unused closure
>   Non-nominal type 'T[]' cannot be extended
>   Expected '{' in extension

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Swift, we'll need to think whether there's a *function* that can do the trick -- outside the methods of a class.

Just like in our case here:

```
contains(theArray, theItem)
```

You can try it in a playground:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
contains(a, 3)
contains(a, 6)
```

I discover a lot of these functions by cmd-clicking on a Swift symbol (example: *Array*) and then by looking around in that file (which seems to be the global file containing all declarations for Swift general classes and functions).

Here's a little extension that will add the "contains" method to all arrays:

```
extension Array {
    func contains<T: Equatable>(item: T) -> Bool {
        for i in self {
            if item == (i as T) { return true }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been doing this and I know it exists, I would just rather go with `theArray.contains(element)` than `contains(theArray,element)`

Comment: @JackyBoy I created a little extension to fulfill your wish :)

Comment: Note that you need to use the optional typecast: `if item == (i as? T)` so you don't crash when the type doesn't match the Array's item type. Also, this method won't work for arrays of optional objects (i.e. `String?[]`)

Comment: @JohnEstropia John, you're definitely right about the optionals... I haven't found a general solution...

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan Check out my answer for a general solution.

Answer (score 3):

To add, the problem is that T is already defined and the Array's definition of T does not conform to Equatable. You can either accomplish what you want by casting (**like the accepted answer**), and risking an invalid cast, or you could pass in a delegate where no casting would be required.

Consider modifying like so:

```
extension Array {
   func contains(comparator: (T)->Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in self {
        if comparator(item) {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Test {
    func arrayContains(){
        var test: Int[] = [0,1,3,4,5]
        //should be true 
        var exists = test.contains({(item)->Bool in item == 0});
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach since "Any" doesn't implement Equatable. A less verbose example is "assert(["one", "two"].contains({$0 == "one"}))"

Answer (score 2):

Not to say that it's impossible, but I haven't yet seen a way to extend structs or classes to put conditions on the original generics, for instance to guarantee `Equatable` or `Comparable` on an Array. However, for your particular issue, instead of extending, you can do something like the following:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
var isIncluded : Bool = arr.bridgeToObjectiveC().doesContain(1)
```